# 127.0.0.1 is not accessible from http. I have to use localhost that is not supported on android device

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, microsoft-graph-api

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not.
If it's a bug I already used github:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3106

if not I need help.
I'm using microsoft-graph for my game in Unity3d to store the save file on one drive user account.
Where I can use localhost everything works, but on android device I have to use 127.0.0.1 as localhost.
For dropbox and google I was able to do it... but microsoft-graph does not work with http on ip localhost like 127.0.0.1 it only works on http for localhost and it require https for 127.0.0.1... Of course HttpListener in c# for loopback only works for http (and since this is a game I need the user to use it on android without strange configurations).
I think this is a bug because boot dropbox and google give you the ability to use http for 127.0.0.1... but if it's not a bug how would you solve this problem? It is even possible to use https in a loopback with HttpListener or something like that without any strange configurations?
You should know that if I manually change the redirect url to http after the login I'm able to make it work.
The only problem is that I don't want to set up a server to redirect a user multiple times.. I want my game to look for the redirect url response in the localhost (that on android should be 127.0.0.1).

I need to know if it's possible to use https with HttpListener (or something like that) for 127.0.0.1 or you know how to workaround this problem without any webapplication.

```
var httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:" + anyfreeportonyourpc + "/");
httpListener.Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a bug. There is just no way to solve this problem if microsoft do not update their code.

EDIT. Finally a simple solution:

```
- just make a simple blog with wordpress
- activate https
- publish your blog in a free site like altervista
- install Insert Headers and Footers
- use this simple code

<script>
if(window.location.href.startsWith("https://yourblogaddress.altervista.org/blog/yourpostpath/")){
var stringPartUrl = window.location.href.substring(numberofcharinyoururl);
window.location.replace("http://localhostor127.0.0.1:yourport/" + stringPartUrl);
}
</script>
```

after that you just need to set `https://yourblogaddress.altervista.org/blog/yourpostpath/` in the new azure portal app and change the OpenURL and redirect_uri in your app (but not the Prefixes.Add url that should be your 127 o localhost url).
Everytime someone log in should oauth to his/her microsoft account that should redirect to your https blog address that should redirect to localhost or 127 and get the code variable to your app that should finally be able to receive the auth code to upload/download files.

The main problem is that your blog should be online and you can only support one port (since you need to redirect one time). The best thing is that you don't need to change the implementation on desktop (since they allow again localhost with regular http in the new portal) and that you don't need a paid domain to do anything.

Comment: That's old news already. It now works with 127.0.0.1. Just make a mobile and native app and use that. you also don't really need client_secret anymore, just use PKCE. That's still an alternative solution that works so I'll keep that here.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is a bug or a feature you talking about but I have a few ideas you can try.

Probably the easiest way to workaround that is to use http://readme.localtest.me/ - This way you can use `http://localtest.me:80` which is a public DNS record pointing back to 127.0.0.1 - Its nice for testing purposes but in this case quite a clever work around.

But as you mentioned it needs to be encrypted so based on the idea above you could to do this on one of your own domains. Get a certificate for it like free [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and just have that point to 127.0.0.1 and use that on your devices.

So say you have a domain called `a.pl` go and create a subdomain `local.a.pl` and set the A record on that sub domain to `127.0.0.1` (This would usually be a server with the web application but in this case we want to use it for a work around) Use lets encrypt to put a certificate on there so you can use HTTPS or maybe self signed will work too, I don't know.

Then in your code you do this

```
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("https://local.a.pl:" + anyfreeportonyourpc + "/");
```

Yes, you will initially need internet connection for your app to go and find the DNS record, and cache it on the mobile device. Setting the TTL to maximum will help to keep it cached for when there is no internet. So once its resolved you can use that domain for every single connection to the local device you need. It just requires that 2 seconds of internet to cache the DNS entry.

Another way to add a hosts lookup somehow... Not sure how but a simple local A record to  `myapp.local` that point back to 127 in the hosts file. This would only be private level lookup for your workaround purposes but adding that record may not be straight forward on mobiles due to excessive abuse in the past.

It also just sounds like the graph server binding is only set to a hostname of `localhost` ... check to see if you can change that or relax it to an IP address. That would solve the root cause of your problem. I know these things have stupid bindings sometimes.

Comment: I think both are not a solution to my problem. The first one because Microsoft graph require a perfect url match (they even want the port). And they require https for anything but localhost (that's why I'm not sure if it's a bug, because 127.0.0.1 should be localhost). Also I already saw that you cannot edit the hosts file on android without root (and it is not a solution for a final user even if it was possible). thank you anyway.

Comment: well then you will have to try and get a localhost certificate installed somehow - In Visual Studio for example this is already available to develop in `https://localhost` I don't know about how to do that on the end clients devices though. Technically it should already be like that to allow for encrypted local services like graph.

Comment: "I don't know about how to do that on the end clients devices though." yes, this is the problem if it is not a bug. I don't really know how to generate certificate for https and do that on clients devices for https://127.0.0.1 from a unity application transparent to the final user.

Comment: just do what localtest does.. but on your own domain with a free cert from lets encrypt then. That should solve your issues

Comment: you should understand that this is not a webapplication. I don't have any domain to cert. And I don't think it's possible to use Lets Encrypt on https://127.0.0.1 of the final user at runtime. Anyway I will try it.

Comment: No- I understand.. But any thing that requires TCP/IP to connect to it sounds it could be connected to the internet. My point is not to have a website but to have a domain that can be cached in the mobile phone form a public location. It is a work around. You can only add hosts by root, ok fine. Then use the public domain mechnism which does the same. make a subdomain on somewhere, put a lets encrypt cert on it, make the A record 127.0.0.1, use that for your connection string. Yes.. you will need internet connection for it to work but setting TTL to max will cache it for very long

Comment: I added more detail to my answer. You not putting a certificate on 127.0.0.1 you are putting a certificate on a random domain, which points to  127.0.0.1 - It doesnt matter what A record you put in the certificate binds to the domain. Its not ideal but your app would need a short internet connection to cache the DNS - i also explained and that's it. It should work until Microsoft fixes that stupid bug.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try it as soon as possible. It's not a problem to get an internet connection (after all the user have to use microsoft graph), the only problem is if I have to own a domain or communicate with an external web application.

Comment: Actually it may not working because of the certificate binding.. but here. try this. `https://local.kula.solutions` It has a record to 127.0.0.1 but still somehow it serves the static text file.. I am a bit confused but I suppose what I thought may work actually will not work... sorry it seems like this a massive problem